# Cannot import 'Callable' from 'collections'?

Tags: python, celery, yolo, yolov8

I'm trying to run a YOLOv8 retrained object detection test, but I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/yolo", line 5, in <module>
    from yolo.script import cli
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yolo/script.py", line 20, in <module>
    from yolo import client
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yolo/client.py", line 39, in <module>
    import keyring
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keyring/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .core import (set_keyring, get_keyring, set_password, get_password,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keyring/core.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import backend
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .util import properties
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keyring/util/properties.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Callable
ImportError: cannot import name 'Callable' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/collections/__init__.py)
```

I've already tried installing gnu-cobol and updating celery, any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: The error is inside the `keyring` package.  Update that package.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `keyring` package

---

If for some reason your project is dependent on earlier version of the module then you can try:

`Callable` is moved form collections to `collections.abc`

```
import collections.abc
collections.Callable = collections.abc.Callable
```

---

Other modules which are moved to collections.abc are:

```
collections.Iterable = collections.abc.Iterable
collections.Mapping = collections.abc.Mapping
collections.MutableSet = collections.abc.MutableSet
collections.MutableMapping = collections.abc.MutableMapping
```

**Disclaimer: This is just a temporary solution where you cannot modify the imports in your scripts because of a third-party import.**

It is always good to have the latest version of the module.